# Time series with two interdependent variables - is it possible?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm undertaking another project in R and I need to run a time series analysis. It's about topics mentioned in media articles and on Twitter. I realized that most probably (and according to past research) the predictive ability goes both ways, just with different lags.
I was wondering if there is any way of actually measuring the level of interdependence? From the time series I can see that, indeed, one serves as a predictor of the values of the other and vice versa (on a different time scale) - but how does one see how strong that two-way influence is?
And considering that I am not a statistician, is it feasible? 
Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Check out Vector Auto-Regression (VAR) methods.

Comment: jesus, I actually knew about VAR but for some reason didn't think about it at all. Thanks so much!

Comment: Non-statistical methods of systems analysis (e.g., Levins' "loop analysis" among *many* others may also fit your bill; Levins, R. (1974). The qualitative analysis of partially specified systems. *Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences*, 231:123–138.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method that answers your question pretty well is Granger Causality.  A few years back I uploaded a short powerpoint on the subject that explains it pretty well in very basic understandable terms.   https://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?searchfrom=header&q=Granger+Causality

The Wikipedia article on the subject is pretty good too. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality

Numerous softwares now have automated Granger Causality tests that run the whole thing automatically for you.

You will notice that a lot of variables are interdependent in a feedback loop.  That is prior values of A influence B (or Granger cause B).  But, prior values of B also influence A.  And, there is often very little difference in statistical significance between the two.  So, you often get ambivalent results like that.

You also get numerous results where you find that A and B do not influence each other much.  I think this may be because of the math underlying Granger Causality that is associated with a high hurdle rate so to speak.  Granger Causality includes a lag term of the variable you are testing.  And, if your variable is strongly autocorrelated it will mask much of the influence that the other variable could have on the tested variable.

To correct for the above, I would simply streamline the Granger Causality regressions down to simply: A = intercept + coef(B t-1).  And, then do it the other way too: B = intercept + coef(A t-1).  And, then I would simply observe which regression has a better Goodness of fit (higher R Square, lower standard error) to see which way the relationship is the strongest.  That's kind of a mini-Granger Causality set up.